# React Native problems on Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, react-native

I install the environment for `react-native`, and try to get `AwesomeProject` running.

On the terminal that opens, I get an `SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode` error pointing to the line:

```
const babel = require('babel-core');
^^^^^`
```

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'It looks like the implementationof **DEV** has changed. Update -[RCTBatchedBridge loadSource:].'`

Is the new version of Xcode and build target being iOS 9, the problem? Or something else?

Comment: very probably it is the javascript dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade Node.js to v4+

Comment: `node --version` is `v4.1.1`

Comment: Hmm, I had the same issue. I was running the macports version of node which was way outdated. After installing the latest version and re-creating the react-native project everything is back to normal.

Comment: make sure , that the terminal thats running the packager , is the right node version , in case you use nvm . differnt terminals can have diffrent node -v

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
dev=true&platform=ios
```

to packager url (AppDelegate.m)

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade react-native to 0.14.2,not 0.17.0 or latest and upgrade Node.js to v4+.